# Программа detab из книги Кернигана и Ритчи

Tags: c

Читая книгу Ритчи и Кернигана я наткнулся на не очень понятное решение к его упражнению 1.20 где надо заменить всю табуляцию на пробелы:
Вот код который я нашел:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define TABINC 8

int main(void)
{
  int nb,pos,c;

  nb = 0;
  pos = 1;

  while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
  {
    if( c == '\t')
    {
      nb = TABINC - (( pos - 1) % TABINC);

      while( nb > 0)
      {
        putchar('#');
        ++pos;
        --nb;
      }
    }
    else if( c == '\n')
    {
      putchar(c);
      pos = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      putchar(c);
      ++pos;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

А вот мой:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  int c;
  while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    if( c == '\t')
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        putchar('#');
    else if( c == '\n')
      putchar(c);
    else
      putchar(c);

  return 0;
}
```

Могли бы вы объяснить что что означают nb и pos в первой программе и зачем нужно это уравнение ?

> nb = TABINC - (( pos - 1) % TABINC);

Comment: Сперва стоит заметить, что авторы книги Dennis M. Ritchie и Brian W. Kernighan - два разных человека.

Comment: Расчет табуляции. Табуляция у вас - это просто 8 символов, а *настоящая* табуляция - это начало дальнейшего текста в новой *позиции табуляции*.

Answer (score 1):

Конструкция `nb = TABINC - (( pos - 1) % TABINC);` рассчитывает, сколько пробелов ещё нужно добавить, что бы дополнить текущую позицию до позиции табуляции. По другому, по умолчанию, табуляция заменяется не на 8 пробелов, а на от 1 до 8 пробелов так, что бы текущая позиция была кратна 8. Собственно указанный код и делает это - если текущая позиция в строке 6 (а pos - это текущий символ, начиная с 1), то значения этого выражения будет `3 (== 8 - ((6-1)%4)`.

Ещё раз. Если строка такая `123t1234t` (где t - это табуляция), то строка должна быть развернута в `123#####1234####`. Ваш код делает это не верно. Он всегда дополняет по восемь пробелов (решеток). То есть, развернет строку как `123########1234########`.

Я не понимаю, почему там решили сделать стартовую позицию равной 1. Если сделать pos = 0, тогда чуточку упрощается начальное выражение - там не нужно делать `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int     i;
12345678^
```

Обратите внимание, что в этом примере два символа табуляции между типом и именем переменной, но 5 пробельных символов никак не делятся на 2 символа табуляции равной ширины. Почему? Потому что символ табуляции не эквивалент строке, состоящей из фиксированного числа пробелов, напротив, символ табуляции при выводе занимает переменное место от до N пробельных символов, в зависимости от настройки ширины табуляции. Поэтому ваш код проще, но задачу решает неверно.

Встретив символ табуляции программа `detab` должна добавить не фиксированное число пробельных символов, а столько, сколько необходимо до следующей сетки табуляции.

```
 nb = TABINC - (( pos - 1) % TABINC);
```

Эта строка кода как раз высчитывает (кстати, это не уравнение, это оператор присваивания), сколько же пробелов необходимо вставить. Пробелов необходимо вставить взять разность длины табуляции (задано константой) от остатка деления позиции текущего символа строки (считая от 0) на длину табуляции

Переменная pos используется для корректного учёта текущей позиции в тексте с учётом символом перевода строки. Без этого некорректным будет, например, форматирование табуляцией в примере:

```
hello
    world
```